# Flowchart to HTML and CSS online tool?

Tags: android, html, css, flowchart

I need a tool where the user can draw an flowchart easily, and export this to a HTML and CSS file. 
My intention to save this HTML code in a database, and get this from my android app, and show this in a Webview.
Do you know some flowchart tool for to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into [Lucid Chart API](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/api_documentation), I know there is an embed code option, which could help you, but there's always a save the charts to an image file.

There might be a specific  tool out there to do that function, but I am guessing it would be difficult to find or require an upfront cost to use. I would anticipate that you most likely will have to strap something together yourself.

Comment: Every tool I have used saves the charts to an image file. Other option is draw.io, that saves the chart to an html, with the diagram encoded. The problem is that the links doesn´t work in webview...